# How to make Bootstrap panel border cut some edege

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel

I want to a cut the some edge part of the border line. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6XNH.jpg) image. In red box.

Basically I want to make the line where the edges should be erased formed.

Comment: can you post some more code please.....?

Comment: SIMPLE BOOTSTRAP PANEL CODE.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could understand your question it is not a good idea, but nevertheless I have made a solution for the same..

```css
.container {width: 300px; height: 200px; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;}
.border-maker {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: solid 5px #000; height: 100%; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
.border-eraser {position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; height: 5px; width: 40%; background: #fff; transform: translateX(-50%);}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border-maker"></div>
  <div class="border-eraser"></div>
 </div>
```

The example you have shown in image was not clear for me to make solution, so if you would like to clear the problem I will improve my answer....!